# Using ‘used to’ in subordinate clauses

Tags: verbs, word-usage, clauses, subordinate-clauses

Is it correct to use the modal verb ‘used to’ in subordinate clauses? For example, could I say, ‘When we used to go to New Delhi, my father and I would shop for music CDs’?
Or must I reserve it only for the main clause and change my sentence to something like, ‘When(ever) we went to New Delhi, my father and I would shop for music CDs’?

Comment: _Used to_ (in the idiom pronounced with an /st/ and not a /zd/) may be used in any tensed clause where it makes sense, main or subordinate.  But it's not a modal verb -- it's a generic perfective (or possibly a perfective generic) construction, dealing with repetiion, past and present. Modals are a different matter.

Comment: It used to be that I couldn't get used to all the discussions of the terminology used to describe subordinate clauses.  Any more I just ignore them.

Comment: The implication of using "used to" is that you don't go to New Delhi any more.

Comment: @Barmar or have changed the circumstances in which you once did.  *When I used to go to the airport, I never had to take off my shoes for the TSA.*

Comment: If 'used to' can be changed like "did use to, didn't use to, etc." it is not a modal, but a verb in simple present tense.  He loved to...; He wrote to...He used to... should hold good. Thus, both sentences OP has exemplified, make sense.

Comment: It sounds a bit odd to me, although I can't quite put my finger on it. I'd say "Often when we went to New Delhi..." or "In the past when we went to New Delhi..." or qualify it like that, rather than using "used to" which seems less clear or less natural.

Answer (score 2):

The usage is a bit off. "when we used to go to New Delhi" has the primary meaning of "the time in which we would habitually go to New Delhi", rather than "each time that we went to New Delhi" as you apparently mean. So it's not incorrect in general to use "used to" in subordinate clauses, but in this particular case it doesn't match the meaning you apparently intend.

Comment: Good spot. // So 'When we used to go to New Delhi, both my father and I had a lot more hair' works. The main clause is past-durative rather than past-iterative.